# Additional Add To Cart button redirecting to checkout on WooCommerce Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, checkout

I need a button on the WooCommerce archive that adds the product to cart and that re-directs the customer to the checkout. I call it "Buy and Checkout".

I'm hooking into the archive by using the `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` action and I have defined the `global $product;` argument.

I then get the product ID and I then define the add to cart url (`atc_url` argument).
Problem is, when clicking on add to cart, the product is not added.

**This is my code so far and I'm not really sure what's wrong here.**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'buy_checkout_on_archive', 20 );
function buy_checkout_on_archive(){

    global $product;

    $pid = $product->get_id();

    $atc_url = wc_get_checkout_url().'?add-to-cart='.$pid;

    $button_class = 'loop-checkout-btn';

    $button_text = __('Buy &amp; Checkout', 'woocommerce');

        if ($product->is_type('simple')){
            echo '<a href="'.$atc_url.'" class="'.$button_class.'">'.$button_text.'</a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do the trick, adding a custom add to cart button on WooCommerce archives that redirect to checkout after adding the product to cart:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'buy_checkout_on_archive', 20 );
function buy_checkout_on_archive(){
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('simple') ){
        $product_id   = $product->get_id();
        $button_url   = '?addtocart='.$product_id;
        $button_class = 'button loop-checkout-btn';
        $button_text  = __('Buy &amp; Checkout', 'woocommerce');

        echo '<a href="'.$button_url.'" class="'.$button_class.'">'.$button_text.'</a>';
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'addtocart_on_archives_redirect_checkout' );
function addtocart_on_archives_redirect_checkout(){
    if( isset( $_GET['addtocart'] ) && $_GET['addtocart'] > 0 ) {
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( intval($_GET['addtocart']) );

        // Checkout redirection
        wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.